# External Javascript file to HTML page

Tags: jquery

Wonder if you might be able to help me with an issue I'm having. I've done some searching but could not find a solution or I'm just not looking in the right places.

Here's my issue:

I have a .js file that runs a script. If put that file in  tags it runs perfectly so I don't think there is something wrong with the file. What I want to do now is to get a button linked to the .js file so whenever someone clicks on the button the javascript appears in my table. Is that possible?

The reason I want to do this is because we have quite a number of these .js files and instead of creating a bunch of html pages for each javascript file I want to use a function that calls a specific javascript file and displays it in a table or  tag whenever a specific button is clicked.

Thank you for assisting me

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, but it sounds like you need to hook the code in your js files to events, instead of just writing to the page in the location they are set. If you post your code I can be of more help.

Comment: Yes, this is possible.  Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: I don't think I get what you are asking. What do you mean with loading a JS file in a table? And load it on a button click?

Comment: Are you trying to display the contents of these JavaScript files?Please could you include one of these JavaScript files and the HTML page so we can see what you are trying to do? You can add them to [Gist](https://gist.github.com/) if they are too large to include here and just copy and paste the relevant parts into the question.

Answer (score 1):

make an ajax call to fetch the javascript file content as String

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

and in the success handler, place the text (file content) in a text-area to display the javascript code

Answer (score 0):

```
 jQuery    

$('button').click(function(){

    $('<script src="yourScript.js"></script>').appendTo('head');
    location.reload();

});
```

Would this work for what you're trying to do?